# z-Index problem -- positioning child over parent's sibling

Tags: css, z-index, layer

I have a situation as in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhKSN.png) below, but what I want is B behind A and -- the tricky part -- b over A.

[image]

How could I do that?

Thanks a lot -- Eric.

Answer (score 3):

While a screenshot is helpful, some HTML would be even better... Only from the screenshot though, I would suggest raising b's `z-index` to 2 or 3. That should fix the problem.

**Update:**  I managed to make it work with the following settings: A: `z-index:2`, `position:absolute` or `fixed`, B: `z-index:1`, `position:static`, b: `z-index:5`, `position:relative`, `absolute`, or `fixed`.

Comment: Hey Andrew, thanks for your comment. 

The example is based on the tool on http://tjkdesign.com/articles/z-index/teach_yourself_how_elements_stack.asp
Should be easy to reproduce there, unfortunately changing the z-index of the inner element won't help.

Comment: @Eric I managed to make it work with the following settings: A: `z-index:2`, `position:absolute or fixed`, B: `z-index:1`, `position:static`, b: `z-index:5`, `position:relative, absolute, or fixed`.

Answer (score 0):

Just took a look at the source code, and it's a complete mess. It looks like the CSS and JavaScript on the page has been auto-generated by Yahoo and uses their API, and the CSS is actually directly implemented by JavaScript by using inline CSS in the HTML, like so:

```
<canvas id="fillAreaA" style="z-index: {javascript variable}" width="300" height="500" />
```

There's probably text on top of it, too, but in short, you shouldn't have any problems with it if you implement it yourself on your own page.

**EDIT:** I'm looking at this several months later, and can't believe how dumb I was. I now know that the JS is from the YUI library. I defer to Andrew's solution.